# R-bridge minimum requirement

Tags: arcgis-10.2, r, arcgis-10.3, r-bridge

The [new R-bridge](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install), unveiled at ESRI UC conference (2015), has a dependency on ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Has anybody tested it with older versions of ArcGIS Desktop? Specificially, I need to know why it depends on 10.3.1. I need to run it on 10.2.

Comment: You would need to compile the R [arcgisbinding](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge) package against 10.2 and install it to R manually (you would not use the Install Binding tool provided, it downloads the 10.3 binaries). Other than that, I can't see anything 10.3 specific in the Python side of things.

Comment: I would point out that the ArcGIS 10.3.1 version is limited to the 32-bit version of R. To use 64-bit R you have to have ArcGIS Professional. This is an irksome limitation that is not necessary. It will make working with spatial objects quite limiting.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans fortunately, that's not the case. You can use the [background geoprocessing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm) installation to connect ArcGIS up with the 64-bit R environment, after installation just make sure your scripts are set to run 'in the background'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting ArcGIS know how to appropriately handle R scripts requires changes to the application. Unfortunately, the release of 10.2.2 predates the existence of this project. The actual integration with R can be used however, by [downloading the release](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge/releases/latest) and manually installing it into R, as shown in [this screencast](https://4326.us/R/zipinst/). That approach, which will give you full access to ArcGIS features from R will work with 10.2.2.<sup>1</sup>

1. [GitHub issue on minimum version](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install/issues/9#issuecomment-144218526)